# Can I make a larger left bracket?

Tags: math-mode, color, brackets

For statements like the one below, I need a large left bracket to precede the array.  `\Biggr\{` is not big enough.  Ideally I could use `\left\{` and make the right bracket white, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do that.

```
\( P(Y = y) = \Biggr\{ 
\begin{array}{l l} 
0.064&amp; \mbox{ for }y = -3 \\ 
0.360 &amp; \mbox{ for }y = 0 \\ 
0.360 &amp; \mbox{ for } y=3 \\ 
0.216 &amp; \mbox{ for } y=6 \\ 
0 &amp; \mbox{ otherwise.} 
\end{array} \)
```

Comment: `\begin{cases}` is what you need.

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to complete small document, which we can compile as it is. On the first sight it seem that you actually look for `cases` environment provided by `amsmath`

Comment: Did you try the `cases` environment?

Comment: In general you can use `left\{` and `\right.`, but (as others have suggested) it's best to use `cases` and related environments (`dcases` etc.) for piecewise definitions.